# select child id of parent with Jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I select the rsMainSlideImage under rsActiveSlide in JQuery?
I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
 $(".rsActiveSlide .rsContent .rsMainSlideImage").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
 });



<div class="rsContainer" style="transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<div class="rsSlide  rsActiveSlide" style="left: 0px;">
<div class="rsContent" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out 0s;">
   <img data-zoom-image="image1.jpg" alt="image description" src="image1.jpg" data-rsw="700" 
class="rsImg rsMainSlideImage" style="width: 765px; height: 984px; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 51px;">

    </div></div>
```

Comment: Your selector seems fine. What errors do you get? Is your jQuery within a document ready call?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is correct make sure code in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/B8MPq/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".rsActiveSlide .rsContent .rsMainSlideImage").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
    });
});
```